# Django: How to use urlresolvers correctly? (Got NoReverseMatch exception)

Tags: python, django

I got a NoReverseMatch exception from my Django project and I have no idea why.

Here is my project layout:

```
project
   openstack_dashboard
       mydashboard
          formpanel
             urls.py
             views.py
```

In the urls.py, I specified the following urlpattern:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns  # noqa
from django.conf.urls import url  # noqa

from .views import IndexView, CreateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
   url(r'^create$', CreateView.as_view(), name="temp_create")
)
```

In the views.py, I specifed the views as usual so I will skip.

When I try to reverse URL from the CreateView, I got the NoReverseMatch error:

```
from openstack_dashboard.dashboards.mydashboard.formpanel.views import CreateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

reverse(CreateView)   # NoReverseMatch exception
reverse("temp_create") # NoReverseMatch exception
```

Here is the full stack trace (reverse(CreateView):

```
>>> reverse(CreateView)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 536, in reverse
return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 456, in          _reverse_with_prefix
(lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'openstack_dashboard.dashboards.mydashboard.formpanel.views.CreateView' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Did I miss something here?

Thanks

Comment: What's the full stacktrace?

Comment: Updated with full stacktrace

Comment: First, I believe `reverse` takes a callable object if you are passing it a view, so you would need to say `CreateView.as_view()` since it's a class-based view. Is this your root urls.py? Did you forget to include patterns for this app in your root urlconf?

Comment: Please also show the main urls.py that includes this one.